# react mui table with collapse : how to align collapse columns with parent columns

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, alignment

I have a list of users i'm mapping on for the main table. 
These users may have a list of contacts on which i map on the collapse table.

My problem is, since the collapse table is a new table, the columns do not align with the parents columns.

[image]

[image]

I simplified my code for some clarity.

The Table :

```
 <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
          <TableHeadComponent
            columnsTitle={columnsTitle} // list of the names of the columns
            rowsData={rowsData?.datas}
            profileType="P1"
          />
            <TableBody>
                // list of users i'm mapping on
                rowsData?.datas?.map((row: any, index: number) => (
                  <TableBodyComponent
                    columnsTitle={columnsTitle}
                    row={row}
                    key={`row-${row?.id}-${index}`}
                    rowsData={rowsData}
                    profileType="P1"
                  />
                ))
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
```

The tableHead :

```
<TableHead
      sx={{
        display: profileType === "P2" ? "none" : "table-header-group",
      }}
    >
      <TableRow>
        <StyledHeadTableCell key={-2} />
        <StyledHeadTableCell key={-1} />
        <StyledHeadTableCell key={-0}>
          <Checkbox
          />
        </StyledHeadTableCell>
        {columnsTitle?.map(
          (item) =>
            item?.isActive && (
              <TableCell
                align="center"
                key={item?.id}
              >
                {item?.title}
              </TableCell>
            ),
        )}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
```

the tableRow :

```
<TableRow
        key={row?.id}
      >
        <TableCell>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="expand row"
            sx={{ display: row?.activeUser?.P2Contacts?.length === 0 && "none" }}
          >
            {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">
          <ActionsIcons iconArray={iconArray} />
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell >
          <Checkbox
          />
        </TableCell>
        {columnsTitle?.map((v, index) => {
          return (
            v?.isActive && (
              <TableCell key={`${row?.id}-${index}`} align="center">
                {flatObject[v?.key as string] as any}// function to get value if nested object
              </TableCell>
            )
          );
        })}
      </TableRow>
      {row?.activeUser?.P2Contacts?.length !== 0 && (
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell sx={{ p: 0 }} colSpan={columnsTitle?.length}>
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <P2Table P2Infos={row?.activeUser?.P2Contacts} />
            </Collapse>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      )}
```

And the table in the collapse:

```
 <Table>
        <TableHeadComponent
          columnsTitle={P2ColumnTitles}
          setCheckedList={setCheckedList}
          rowsData={P2Infos}
          profileType="P2"
        />
        <TableBody>
          {P2Infos?.map((row: any, index: number) => (
            <P2TableBodyComponent
              columnsTitle={P2ColumnTitles}
              row={row}
              key={`row-${row?.id}-${index}`}
              rowsData={P2Infos}
              profileType="P2"
            />
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
```

I tried to put a fixed width on the columns (by adding a width key on the columnsTitle object and pass it on the tableCell but only the collapse table applied the width and i'm not sure it would still be a solution because, first, it would not be responsive and secondly i put a display none on the tableHead of the collapse table).

I also thought of putting a ref on the parent tableHead to pass it to the collapsed tableHead but since I don't display the collapsed tableHead, it won't work.

Any ideas would be great.